# Ubuntu 22.04 - Browser malware issue, sites redirecting to winbigdrip.life , endwisvote.live appcloudvalue.com basketballidentity.cn

Tags: ubuntu, browser, malware, ubuntu-22.04

I'm facing a strange problem on both of my chrome and firefox browsers. The sites are getting re-directed to other sites like winbigdrip.life , endwisvote.live appcloudvalue.com basketballidentity.cn (one after the other)

Some times I also get "Your connection is private" browser error, even if the site has a valid SSL certificate.

**My chrome version:** Version 114.0.5735.198 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**My Firefox version:** 115.0.2 (64-bit)

I tried the following and none of them helped me,

1. Uninstalled google chrome and re-installed
2. Cleared cache, cookies and finally deleted the ~/.config/google-chrome folder

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and fixed it. My router was probably hacked and the DNS was modified to the below given ones.

[image]

The possible reason for this could be,

1. I had static IP for my router
2. I had disabled firewall for some testing purposes and left it

I rectified the above two issues and now it's stable. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks, for the help. I had the same issue with ISP router which has default maintenance user. The web pancel was accessible from the world, and robots changed the dns server.